# Dynamically hide/show textboxs when a checkbox clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

After a bit of JQ research, I updated the question because it upset some, rightly, hands-up! When a checkbox is clicked content of corresponding  should be visible and vice verse. How can I do it?
Thanks

**JQ:**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $('div.accessories div.acc-wrapper input:checkbox').click(function(event) {

            if($(this).prop('checked')) {
                $('div.accessories div.acc-wrapper div.field').show();
            } else {
                $('div.accessories div.acc-wrapper div.field').hide();
            }

        });
    });
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="accessories">
    <div class="acc-wrapper">
        <label>Row 1</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="cname_1" name="abc" value="1" />
        <br />
        <div class="field" style="display:none;">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="name_1" name="name" value="" />
            <label>Surname</label>
            <input type="text" id="surname_2" name="surname" value="" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="acc-wrapper">
        <label>Row 2</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="cname_2" name="abc" value="1" />
        <br />
        <div class="field" style="display:none;">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="name_2" name="name" value="" />
            <label>Surname</label>
            <input type="text" id="surname_2" name="surname" value="" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="acc-wrapper">
        <label>Row 3</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="cname_3" name="abc" value="1" />
        <br />
        <div class="field" style="display:none;">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="name_3" name="name" value="" />
            <label>Surname</label>
            <input type="text" id="surname_3" name="surname" value="" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use the jquery for hide and show any component on any event by using `hide()` and `show()` methods..!!!

For Example:

```
$("#<your component id here>").click(function() {
     $('#<your component id here>').hide();
});
```

Comment: And try to use the change(function(){}); instead of the click function as you want to show it again on uncheck.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably perfect for you:

```
$("#checkboxID").change(function(){
    $("#textboxID").toggle();
});
```

toggle automatically alternates between show and hide